# How to discriminate the union of React contexts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I have two types of React contexts that I need to be able to determine the type of (mobile and desktop). How can I do so in a type-safe manner?

I have tried writing a user defined type guard that takes advantage of the following property: `React.Context<LayoutContextType>` being equivalent to `React.Context<DesktopLayoutContextType> | React.Context<MobileLayoutContextType>`.

However, I appear to be mistaken in assuming they are equivalent.

```js
interface ILayoutStateBase {
  nightMode: boolean
}

interface ILayoutContextBase<
  StateType extends ILayoutStateBase,
  Kind extends 'desktop' | 'mobile'
> {
  kind: Kind
  state: StateType
}

interface IDesktopState extends ILayoutStateBase {
  modalOpen: boolean
}

interface IMobileState extends ILayoutStateBase {
  sidebarOpen: boolean
}

type DesktopLayoutContextType = ILayoutContextBase<IDesktopState, 'desktop'>
type MobileLayoutContextType =  ILayoutContextBase<IMobileState, 'mobile'>

type LayoutContextType =
  | DesktopLayoutContextType
  | MobileLayoutContextType


// below results in:
/**
 * Type 'Context<ILayoutContextBase<IDesktopState, "desktop">>' 
 *   is not assignable to type 'Context<LayoutContextType>'.
 */
const isDesktopLayout = (
  ctx: React.Context<LayoutContextType>
): ctx is React.Context<DesktopLayoutContextType> => {
  return true // how can I do this?
}
```

I expect TypeScript to be able to recognise that `React.Context<LayoutContextType>` is equivalent to `React.Context<DesktopLayoutContextType> | React.Context<MobileLayoutContextType>` and allow me to use the displayName property to distinguish them.

However, I get the error message in the supplied code:

`Type 'Context<ILayoutContextBase<IDesktopState, "desktop">>' is not assignable to type 'Context<LayoutContextType>'.`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry in advance, as my answer may not be complete, but it may help.

1. Why below code *could not be compiled*?

   ```
   const isDesktopLayout = (
       ctx: React.Context<LayoutContextType>
   ): ctx is React.Context<DesktopLayoutContextType> => {
       return true // how can I do this?
   }
   ```

   Lets look at `React.Context<T>` type. It has `Provider` and `Consumer` which both use type `T` and use it as type of argument `props`. `T` is not used anywhere, except as argument type.

   This leads to compilation error. To understand why, look at simplified example below. Here is a function, which accepts callback.

   ```
   function f1 (callback: ((props: string | boolean) => void)) {}
   ```

   Trying to call `f1` with `callback` following callback will give error

   ```
   f1((props: string) => {});  // Type string | boolean is not assignable to type string
   ```

   Essentially the same is happens when you try to write type guard. `React.Context<LayoutContextType>` has `Provider` and `Consumer` defined as functions accepting `props` of type `LayoutContextType` (with some modifications, but this does not metter). And you cannot assign context `React.Context<DesktopLayoutContextType>` with `Provider` and `Consumer` defined as functions accepting `props` of type `DesktopLayoutContextType`.

   Luckily, this issue is easily solved by using union of contexts, like below

   ```
   const isDesktopLayout = (
       ctx: React.Context<DesktopLayoutContextType> | 
   React.Context<MobileLayoutContextType>
   ): ctx is React.Context<DesktopLayoutContextType> => {
       return true // how can I do this?
   }
   ```
2. Second issue is harder to resolve. Type guard is used in runtime to find type of `ctx`. But the only difference between `React.Context<DesktopLayoutContextType>` and `React.Context<MobileLayoutContextType>` is types of arguments. In runtime, there is no way to find what type of argument callback function wants to accept. As JavaScript is dynamic language, callback may be called with any number of arguments of any types. And we cannot know in advance, what type and number of arguments will be.

   So one way to distinguish contexts in runtime can be `diplayName` property (as you suggested). It should be set during context creation, not changed after it, and checked in type guard. This can be done like this

   ```
   const isDesktopLayout = (
       ctx: React.Context<DesktopLayoutContextType> | 
       React.Context<MobileLayoutContextType>
   ): ctx is React.Context<DesktopLayoutContextType> => {
       if (ctx.displayName === undefined) throw 'context displayName is undefined!'
       return ctx.displayName === 'desktop'
   }
   ```

   But this solution is not bound to types, but to value of `displayName` which can be changed in any place in code, which may potentially lead to bugs.